# how to test view text within a range using espresso android

Tags: android, android-studio, range, android-espresso, android-testing

I know that we can use expresso to check view outputs as such: `onView((withId(R.id.text_view_name))).check(matches(withText("text_value_here")));` to see if outputs are as expected, but what if we want to make sure it is within a certain range of values? For instance, not below 0.

How can you write test code using espresso that makes sure a UI value is below, above, or within a certain range of values?

Comment: Most likely you will need to write your own matcher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done easily with a custom matcher:

```
    public class TextViewValueMatcher extends TypeSafeMatcher<View> {
        @Override
        protected boolean matchesSafely(View item) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) item;
            String value = textView.getText().toString();
            boolean matching = <here your condition on the value>;
            return matching;
        }

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {

        }
    }
```

And then used as the following:

```
Espresso.onView(withId(<some_id>)).check(matches(new TextViewValueMatcher()));
```

Comment: @Code-Apprentice thanks for the remark, I edited my answer.

Comment: This answer is great! For the OP: you can modify this to return the matcher from a factory function, something like `isBetween()`, if you want a fluent API similar to the default matchers. You will also need to define the function in such a way that you can pass in `min` and `max` values.

Comment: Perfect! I made the new custom class and had to convert the string to int, but it functions as intended to make sure int is not less than 0. I think I can figure out the rest for min and max value checking.

Comment: @Mr.Drew I'm happy it helped!